# what do && and || mean in the following code

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Reading highstock source codes, but confused the following codes:

```
textLineHeight = textStyles && textStyles.lineHeight,

wrapper.height = (height || bBox.height || 0) + 2 * padding;

cHeight = (old && chart.oldChartHeight) || chart.chartHeight;
```

Thanks

Comment: javascript and (&&) operator & or (||) operator
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: @user2181397, he asks "in the following code"

Comment: @slick, operators change with respect to code, is that what you mean?

Comment: A general article about this - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textLineHeight = textStyles && textStyles.lineHeight;
```

means set `textLineHeight` to `textStyles.lineHeight` if `textStyles` is truthy and it has a property `lineHeight` which is also truthy.

`&&` is often referred to as the guard operator in JavaScript, since its short circuiting evaluation ensures that `textStyles.lineHeight` will not be evaluated unless `textStyles` is defined. This avoids an error if it may indeed be undefined.

```
wrapper.height = (height || bBox.height || 0) + 2 * padding;
```

Here, the `||` means use `height` if it is truthy otherwise use `bBox.height` if that is truthy, and finally fallback to `0` if neither are truthy. `||` is often called the default operator in JavaScript as it allows one to specify a value to use in case the expression on its left hand side is falsy.